# File is being used by another process - using FileInfo

Tags: c#, io

I have an SQL Script file where there is a specific line that I want to manipulate at runtime. I came up with the following for that and it works fine. However, I get an exception when trying to run it again, saying the file is being used by another process. Seems like the file is not being closed, but I cannot figure out where and why.

I have a button that does the following among other things:

```
OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog() { FileName = "Document", DefaultExt = ".csv", Filter = "Comma Seperated File (.csv)|*.csv" };

Nullable<bool> result = dialog.ShowDialog();

string filename = "";

if (result == true)
{
    filename = dialog.FileName;
}

updateSQLScript(filename);

FileInfo file = new FileInfo("\\Tools_TextileMagazine\\CSharp_Template\\Tools_TextileMagazine\\AdditionalFiles\\SQLQuery1.sql");

string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(clsConstants.LOCALDB_CONN_STRING);
Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
```

The method updateSQLScript(filename) only does the following:

```
string[] arrLine = File.ReadAllLines(clsConstants.PATH_TO_SQL_SCRIPT);

arrLine[9] = String.Format("FROM '{0}'", filename);

//THIS IS WHERE THE EXCEPTION IS THROWN THE SECOND TIME I CLICK THE BUTTON
File.WriteAllLines(clsConstants.PATH_TO_SQL_SCRIPT, arrLine);
```

So it seems the other processes happening in the button event is interfering with my updateSQLScript method. I couldn't figure out how to close the file properly before running the method. As far as I could read, I need to use a using statement, but I am not sure how to implement it in this scenario.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Change "string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();" to " string script = file.ReadAllLines();".

Comment: Are `clsConstants.PATH_TO_SQL_SCRIPT` and "\\Tools_TextileMagazine\\CSharp_Template\\Tools_TextileMagazine\\AdditionalFiles\\SQLQuery1.sql" the same?

Comment: You probably need to dispose the `StreamReader` created when calling `file.OpenText`. You can use an `using` block. See the example on the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.opentext(v=vs.110).aspx) for this method at MSDN.

Comment: You have another problem too. OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() does not return a Nullable<bool>, it returns a DialogResult enum.

Comment: @juharr Oh, yeah they actually are, I just made that class containing constants and forgot to replace that path.

Comment: @RenniePet To be completely honest, I just read the example at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried running your code, but I think it's this line that's the problem:

```
string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
```

The OpenText() method returns a StreamReader that needs to be closed. Try something like:

```
string script;
using (StreamReader reader = file.OpenText())
{
    script = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: I tried it out and it seems to be working the way I want it to. Thanks!